# When is it safe to do a make deinstall?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd

So I followed [this post on the FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/watching-spotify-and-listening-to-netflix-in-2023.90695/#post-626065)

It was asking me a lot of prompts and I was like "I'm just going to see
if it works".

After it failed to compile I was like "let me remove it". So I did a

```
make deinstall clean
```

After about 30 mins I went back to the terminal where it was and it was skipping packages that weren't there and eventually I just stopped it.

Went to `startx` and I was missing lots of modules. I reinstalled and everything is working again expect no spotify.

Question is when is it safe to use `make deinstall`?

I was wondering since the forum post had me in one directory that wasn't
official is that the reason why it removed stuff at the root level?

Comment: If compilation fails, there is nothing to uninstall but `make clean` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options to manage a failed port building: `make clean`, `make deinstall` or `pkg_delete port`.

port manpages:

```
clean       Remove the expanded source code.  This recurses to de-
            pendencies unless NOCLEANDEPENDS is defined.

deinstall   Remove  an  installed port from the system, similar to
            pkg-delete(8).
```

Comment: Why did it break my whole system? I think I did a make BATCH=1 make deinstall now that I remember. That should still only remove one port right ? Also if the port was in my home dir why would it be trying to remove ports in /use/ports ?